# dynamically setting schema name and table name in an update query

Tags: sql, db2, prepared-statement

I have an update query as below:

```
UPDATE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME = VALUE;
```

I am passing the below query as a String inside a prepared statement setter:

```
UPDATE ?.? SET ? = ?
```

And inside my prepared statement setter java class, I am setting the values as below:

```
ps.setString(1, "mySchema");
ps.setString(2, "myTable");
ps.setString(3, "myColumn");
ps.setString(4, "myValue");
```

However, on running the java program which prepares above query and runs it I am getting below error:

```
DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601
```

How can I dynamically create the query in the way I have described above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use parameterization (i.e. `?`) to set the schema or table name.  Instead, you just need to insert the correct table into the string in Java before you prepare the statement.

Comment: just want to point out that building a sql string opens the risk of SQL injection attacks.